# Conditional update in an database table using 2 separate buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have created 2 forms "Hire" and "Work" on a single page for an application using bootstrap.

Each form updates its respective table in the database. When I click the "Hire" button it should update its specific database table and same for "Work" button.

```
<div align="center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Looking to Hire</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@fat">Looking for Work</button>
          </div>
```

This is for a single form. How can I use a conditional statement to update the correct table corresponding to the form that is submitted.

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'skill') or die('Error in Conection');
$title = $_POST['title'];
$details = $_POST['detail'];
$hours = $_POST['hours'];
$skills = $_POST['skills'];
$payment = $_POST['payment'];
$query = "INSERT INTO employer_post (title, details, hours, skills, payment) values ('$title', '$details', '$hours', '$skills', '$payment')";
mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Error in Connection');
echo 'Job Added Succesfully!'; mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

I am using html5,css3,JS and PHP. I am new to this and I have no idea about how to do this. Kindly help me with an example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Stark and welcome to SO (StackOverflow). I see you have just joined us. We strive to be a wonderful community and provide people with solutions to their coding problems as best we can. There are some basic fundamentals to [asking a good question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and consequently getting more experienced users to help you. In addition, most of us would like to see that you have put some effort into solving your problem. Show us what you've tried and what the results were. Again, welcome to SO!

Comment: Hi Kuya. I have added some part of code.

Comment: Show us the "sql update" code you are using for the two buttons to update the database tables and tell us what the results or errors are.

Comment: All I have created is 2 buttons "Hire" and "Work" with different forms for each. I have also created separate database tables for each button using CREATE statement. I dont know about how to specifically update respective database tables when I click Hire and same for Work. Atleast give me an idea so I can proceed. Any help would be appriciable.

Comment: This is for single form but now I want 2 forms for a conditional update.<?php

$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'skill')

or die('Error in Conection');

$title = $_POST['title'];

$details = $_POST['detail'];

$hours = $_POST['hours'];

$skills = $_POST['skills'];

$payment = $_POST['payment'];


$query = "INSERT INTO employer_post (title, details, hours, skills, payment) values ('$title', '$details', '$hours', '$skills', '$payment');";
   
mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
or die('Error in Connection');

echo 'Job Added Succesfully!';

mysqli_close($dbc);
?>

Comment: You can write an insert statement, but don't know how to write an update statement. Correct?

Comment: I do know even to update but please try to understand what I mean. How should I just do an conditional update. If I click on Hire it should insert form data into its own table and same for Work button. So tell should I use an if-condition or onclick event?

Comment: Both tables (work and hire) have the exact same fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for the series of comments/questions. I never like to post an answer if I don't have all the information I need to make the answer accurate.

Regardless of my last comment above you can accomplish what you want with this...

Place this element in your "hire" form...

```
<input type="hidden" name="MM_update" id="MM_update" value="hire" />
```

Place this element in your "work" form...

```
<input type="hidden" name="MM_update" id="MM_update" value="work" />
```

Then you can use this conditional statement...

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "hire")) {
    // update sql process for hire table
}
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "work")) {
    // update sql process for work table
}
```

Comment: Hi Kuya. Thank you for understanding. It does work wherein I can insert into specific tables but I am facing a new problem. Both the forms are displaying at a time on the same page. Instead of hiding them under a button both buttons and forms display at a time. Can you help me?

Comment: New problems typically should mean a new question. New questions help make answers relevant to the question asked, the help the community and help the one who asks and the one who answers. Please ask this as a new question and post a link (copy/paste the question url) to the new question in the comments here. I will be happy to answer your new question.

Comment: Hi Kuya. Thank you for reply. Follow this link as you told. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346646/how-to-hide-forms-underneath-buttons

Comment: @Stark - I'm not in front of my computer right now (this is via iphone app). I have your answer prepared. Please give me a few hours. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a tonne Kuya. Take your time. Cheers!